# Creating a text entry in excel style

Tags: python, tkinter, cells

Is there a possible way to set up a table within a window like in excel?

I want to import values from a database table and store them into a excel-like table.

Edit: Cells in the table should be changeable directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a module named [TkTable](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTable) for doing this. it will give you the full table support.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tktable

root = tk.Tk()
table = tktable.Table(root, rows=10, cols=4)
table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```